# Excel formula and conditioning formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to change the colour on columns based on the date and values. IN  column "A" I have dates (from 01/ Jan 2021 until 20 Jan 2021) and on "B"column has PAID and NOT PAID statements.
I want to write a formula which will satisfy this condition:

If dates is <= today and the value of column B is NOT PAID then show the colour of column "A" as RED otherwise Green

I try to put this formula:
=IF(A3<=TODAY(),ANDIF(B3="NOT PAID",Green,RED))

Comment: You say “does not work” — what have you tried? Where are you stuck? (You do know what conditional formatting is and how to use it, right?) … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Try to give more details. 
> I try to put this formula: =IF(A3<=TODAY(),ANDIF(B3="NOT PAID",Green,RED))

It does not work with your formula, but anyway where did you put it exactly?

Comment: I tried this now in conditional formatting by selecting formula  :  AND($A$2<=TODAY(),B2="UNPAID").....I put the format of color as RED, but it doesn't work.none of the cells with less than today date changes color.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very easy Conditional Formatting ("CF") rule to set up.

Highlight the range of cells you want the rule to apply to making sure you highlight cell A1, then the rest of the cells. Then enter the CF functionality (from the Home tab of the Ribbon menu system). Choose to set up a new rule and tell it you wish to use a formula to determine whether to apply it or not (that is the last selection in the top half of the dialog box).

It will ask for the formula. Paste the following:

```
=AND(A1<TODAY(),B1="NOT PAID")
```

(You don't need anything including the `IF()` function because the CF rules are an IF themselves:  anything entered in them is treated like the first part of an `IF()`, the part which is tested for being TRUE or FALSE, so you don't need to use the `IF()`, just that little part of it.)

After pasting the above formula, set the formatting desired, then you're done.

If you highlighted the range and the cell in the range that is white rather than grayed out is NOT A1, then use that cell's address in the formula above, and its companion in column B as well. So if that cell is A23, use A23 and B23. Or select the range again, this time selecting A1 first...

Everything works great after doing the above.